# Describe Icons similar to \DeclareMacro

Tags: two-column, documentation

I would like to describe icons in a `column`- or `table`-wise layout. In my opinion a `table` is not the best tool for this task:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext, longtable, tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu} [c] {lX}
\hline
\rule{4cm}{4cm} & \blindtext \\ 
\rule{4cm}{2cm} & \blindtext\blindtext \\ 
\rule{2cm}{4cm} & \blindtext \\ 
\rule{2cm}{2cm} & \blindtext \\ 
\hline
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

I took a look in documentations of LaTeX packages and saw the macro `\DeclareMacro{}` to document macros. Unfortunately, I did not find the source code of this macro, because I think this would be a good starting point for my task.

How would you describe icons with a similar layout? Is it possible to use a `column` environment?

Comment: How big are the icons?

Comment: Mostly small, like 1-2cm per width and height. However, I would like to use the layout with icons which are as big as the rules in the MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list like `itemize`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\myicon}[1]{\smash{\raisebox{-0.85\height}{\includegraphics[width=15mm]{#1}}}}
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
\item Test
\item Test
\end{itemize}

\blindtext

\begin{itemize}
\item[\myicon{example-image}] \blindtext 
\item[\myicon{example-image-a}] \blindtext\blindtext 
\item[\myicon{example-image-b}]  \blindtext 
\item[\myicon{example-image}] \blindtext 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As noted by egreg, you can load `adjustbox` package with `export` option, then certain keys (like `valign`) become available for `\includegraphics`. Here is the sample.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\myicon}[1]{\includegraphics[width=15mm,valign=t,set depth=0pt]{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\myicon{example-image}] \blindtext
\item[\myicon{example-image-a}] \blindtext\blindtext
\item[\myicon{example-image-b}]  \blindtext
\item[\myicon{example-image}] \blindtext
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Or with `paracol`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{paracol}
\newcommand{\myicon}[1]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{#1}}
\newcommand{\myicons}[2]{%
\columnratio{0.35}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\myicon{#1}
\switchcolumn
#2
\end{paracol}
}

\begin{document}
\myicons{example-image}{\blindtext}
\myicons{example-image-a}{\blindtext\blindtext}
\myicons{example-image-b} {\blindtext}
\myicons{example-image}{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `\smash` you could use `adjustbox` and its `valign=t` option; if you do `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`, then you can directly say `\includegraphics[width=15mm,valign=t,set depth=0pt]{filename}`

Comment: I hope you also tested it. ;-)

Comment: @egreg Is there anything wrong? If you say some thing, I am of the opinion that I need not check. `:-)`.  I have tested it for sure.

Comment: Thanks! I like your `itemize` solution. However, when I add some text before the item list, the icons are in the margin. I edit your first code, I hope that was ok.

Comment: @Dirk No problem. :-)

Comment: Fine. Do you have a solution for the corresponding problem? I add `[leftmargin=\dimexpr\parindent+15mm]` as an option to the `itemize` environment, but when I change to `parskip=full` in the document, this option is not correct.

Comment: @Dirk Difficult to predict with little information. May be ask a new question with full details?