# Horizontal space in lists with image labels

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize, enumitem

I construct a list with icons to document. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext, enumitem, graphicx, longtable, tabu}
\newcommand{\myicon}[1]{%
    \smash{%
        \raisebox{\dimexpr0.5\baselineskip-\height}{#1}%
    }
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=4cm]
\item[\myicon{\rule{4cm}{4cm}}] \blindtext
\item[\myicon{\rule{2cm}{4cm}}] \blindtext\blindtext 
\item[\myicon{\rule{4cm}{2cm}}] \blindtext 
\item[\myicon{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}] \blindtext 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the first box is too far left. I can correct it by `leftmargin=\dimexpr\parindent+4cm`, but when I change `parskip` in the document to e.g. `parskip=full`, the box is wrong again.

How is it possible to enter a good horizontal space to the list?

How far does the upper box on my example extend in the left margin of the document?

The code comes mainly from this [first question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242062/describe-icons-similar-to-declaremacro/242067).

Comment: Well, I delete my answer then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the option of the `itemize` environment to `[labelindent=4cm, leftmargin=*]`. This solves my problem.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext, enumitem, graphicx, longtable, tabu}
\newcommand{\myicon}[1]{%
    \smash{%
        \raisebox{\dimexpr0.5\baselineskip-\height}{#1}%
    }
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{itemize}[labelindent=4cm, leftmargin=*]
\item[\myicon{\rule{4cm}{4cm}}] \blindtext
\item[\myicon{\rule{2cm}{4cm}}] \blindtext\blindtext 
\item[\myicon{\rule{4cm}{2cm}}] \blindtext 
\item[\myicon{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}] \blindtext 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]