# `fontspec` changes indention of itemize

Tags: indentation, fontspec, enumitem

When I add the `fontspec` package, the items in an `itemize` environment get an additional indention. You find the code in the following example, it is mainly from this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242116/horizontal-space-in-lists-with-image-labels):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext, enumitem, fontspec}

\newcommand{\myicon}[1]{%
    \smash{%
        \raisebox{\dimexpr0.5\baselineskip-\height}{#1}%
    }
}

\setlist{nosep}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{itemize}[labelindent=4cm, leftmargin=*]
\item[\myicon{\rule{4cm}{4cm}}] \blindtext
\end{itemize}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `rule` square does not align with the text.

When I remove the `fontspec` package the indention is correct:
[image]

How is it possible to keep the correct indention with the `fontspec´ package?

Comment: I can't see your problem, but there is spurious space in your \myicon definition, and I would probably use `[labelwidth=4cm, leftmargin=!,align=left]`

Comment: I do not understand why I get an additional indention with the `fontspec` package. Where do I have the spurious space? I tried your option, unfortunately the rule jumps into the text.

Comment: Your code works. I was to hectic and did not change the first option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably in the different value of the em; but your way of setting the `itemize` is wrong:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum, enumitem,adjustbox}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand{\myicon}[1]{%
  \adjustbox{valign=t,set depth=0pt}{#1}%
}

\setlist{nosep}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{itemize}[labelindent=-4cm, leftmargin=\dimexpr4cm+\labelsep]
\item[\myicon{\rule{4cm}{4cm}}] \lipsum[1]
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I used `\adjustbox` because it's easier.

The output with or without `fontspec` is the same.

[image]

Comment: We now have three possible options for the itemize environment. Which one is correct and why aren't the others?

Comment: @Dirk There are several ways to do the same thing with `enumitem`.

Comment: I see. ;) Why do you think my way is wrong?

Comment: @Dirk Because it doesn't work. `;-)`

Comment: Good answer. `:)` One question: The top of the `rule` is a bit higher than the top of the corresponding textline "Lorem ipsum...". Is it possible to align this?

Comment: @Dirk Use different options of `\adjustbox` or your original code.

Comment: Now I use the `adjustbox` in the following way: `\adjustbox{valign=T, raise=\fontcharht\font\`X, set depth=0ex}{#1}`. This aligns the image / icon with the top of a capital letter.